# Pattern for querying the database asynchronously in getChildrenCursor() method of CursorTreeAdapter class

Tags: android, asynchronous, expandablelistadapter

I've implemented a custom Adapter for a ExpandableListView which I extended from the [CursorTreeAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorTreeAdapter.html) class. Everything is working as expected.

But I'm wondering if there's pattern or some kind of best practice on how to asynchronously  query the database in the [getChildrenCursor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorTreeAdapter.html#getChildrenCursor%28android.database.Cursor%29) method of the adapter class. At the moment I'm passing my SQLiteOpenHelper class to the constructor of my adapter and use it in [getChildrenCursor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorTreeAdapter.html#getChildrenCursor%28android.database.Cursor%29) to query the database synchronously on the UI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[getChildrenCursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorTreeAdapter.html#getChildrenCursor%28android.database.Cursor%29) says:

> If you want to asynchronously query a
>   provider to prevent blocking the UI,
>   it is possible to return null and at a
>   later time call setChildrenCursor(int,
>   Cursor).

So, in `getChildrenCursor()`, start an `AsyncTask` and return null. In the `onPostExecute()` method call `setChildrenCursor()`

Comment: Alternatively, you can have a look at this file: `ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList2.java` (in SDK's samples).

Answer (score 3):

You could also use a `CursorLoader` instead of subclassing `AsyncTask` to asynchronously query a provider.

```
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    if (id != -1) {
        // child cursor
        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), childrenUri,
                CHILDREN_PROJECTION, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
    } else {
        // group cursor
        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), groupsUri,
                GROUPS_PROJECTION, selection, null, sortOrder);
    }

}

public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    int id = loader.getId();
    if (id != -1) {
        // child cursor
        if (!data.isClosed()) {
            try {
                mAdapter.setChildrenCursor(id, data);
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                Log.w("TAG",
                        "Adapter expired, try again on the next query: "
                                + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

    } else {
        // group cursor
        mAdapter.setGroupCursor(data);
    }
}

public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    int id = loader.getId();
    if (id != -1) {
        // child cursor
        mAdapter.setChildrenCursor(id, null);
    } else {
        // group cursor
        mAdapter.setGroupCursor(null);
    }
}
```

And in your adapter class you can override the `getChildrenCursor()` method like this:

```
protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor groupCursor) {
    // Given the group, we return a cursor for all the children within that group
    int id = groupCursor.getInt(groupCursor
            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Groups._ID));
    mActivity.getLoaderManager().initLoader(id, null,mFragment);
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611927/simplecursortreeadapter-and-cursorloader

Comment: In `onLoadFinished`, why do you check if the cursor is closed?